# Replace dot in middle of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say we have an array (new line separated) like:

```
hello
example.com
test.
something.
 aspacefront
test
test.us
```

to be an array

```
hello
example(dot)com.
test.
something.
 aspacefront
test
test(dot)us
```

**Can this be done with a regex?**

What I've up to loop the array then replace to (dot) with this regex `\b[^a-zA-Z\40]\b.` but it will be example(dot)om rather then example(dot)com.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you mean by "array"? This looks (like @Confusion noted) more like a multiline string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution:

```
result = subject.replace(/\b\.\b/g, "(com)");
```

This means "Replace a dot only if it is preceded and followed by an alphanumeric character".

Comment: He seems to use a single multiline string as an array, so you might need an `m` modifier in addition to the `g`.

Comment: @Confusion: No, why? My regex doesn't contain any `^`s or `$`s whose meaning would be affected by the `/m` modifier.

Comment: No, you are right, it doesn't matter. I thought `/m` also influenced the meaning of `\b`, but a quick perusal of [the pcre docs](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) show that isn't the case.